# Should i go for SqlDataReader or SqlDataAdapter class for returning a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, using, sqlconnection

I have written the below code. I want to know if i can improve it any further.

```
public static DataTable GetDepartments()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "proc_GetDepartments";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;

}
```

Here i have used SqlDataAdapter. What would be the SqlDataReader way to write it. Also which one is better. Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: use the one you have since you are filling directly in a data table `:)` you can also use `SqlDataReader` but seems pointless to me since you have no modification on the value from the resultset.

Comment: _which one is better_ They are two different things. What is your real question?

Comment: @SonerGönül they both can be used to return datatable...wanted to which one is faster/better...also how can i implement `SqlDataReader` above.

Comment: @JW웃 so if want some modification on the result set...that when i need to use SqlDataReader?

Comment: @user2322507 `SqlDataAdapter` is using with the a `DataTable`. It can fill a `DataTable` with a table from your SQL. `SqlDataReader` reads database rows _one-by-one_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also which one is better?

As I said in my [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884188/should-i-go-for-sqldatareader-or-sqldataadapter-class-for-returning-a-datatable#comment24360093_16884188), they are two different things. Apples and oranges..

`SqlDataAdapter` is using with the a `DataTable`. It can fill a `DataTable` with a table from your SQL. `SqlDataReader` reads database rows *one-by-one*.

In your case, I don't see any reason to use `SqlDataReader` since you want to return a `DataTable`. Go for `SqlDataAdapter` ;)

> ..also if u can add the code for SqlDataReader using using.

Sure. But as I said, you can't use `DataTable` with `SqlDataReader`. But hey.. Here is how you can get values with `SqlDataReader`;

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    int firstcell = reader.GetInt32(0);    // I assume your first column is int.
    string secondcell = reader.GetString(1);  // I assume your second column is string.
    string thirdcell = reader.GetString(2); // I assume your third column is string.
    Console.WriteLine("FirstCell = {0}, SecondCell = {1}, ThirdCell = {2}", firstcell, secondcell , thirdcell);
}
```

Comment: seems logical now....thanks for ur input...also if u can add the code for SqlDataReader using using...would have been of great help.

Comment: You should be very careful when using SqlDataReader to act upon each record, until youre finish looping through the rows the table will be locked and other users will get applications hanging waiting for table locks. Disabling the lock can be even worse, since its possible to read duplicate rows, parts of uncommitted transactions and all sorts of horrible things can happen

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlDataReader if you want to loop each record and do some manipulation data inside the looping, but if you want to put the data on the dataset or datatable and then want to bind it to asp.net controls (for e.g: GridView, ComboBox, etc.) then use SqlDataAdapter.

Here is how to use SqlDataReader anyway.

```
using System;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

  class ConnectToSqlConnection {
    static void Main(string[] args)  {
      String sConn = "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        String sSQL = "select id, firstname, lastname from Employee";

      SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
      oConn.Open();

      SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, oConn);
      SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader();

      int idxID = oReader.GetOrdinal("id");
      int idxFirstName = oReader.GetOrdinal("firstname");
      int idxLastName = oReader.GetOrdinal("lastname");

      while(oReader.Read()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
          oReader.GetValue(idxID),
          oReader.GetValue(idxFirstName),
          oReader.GetValue(idxLastName));
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should be very careful when using SqlDataReader to act upon each record, until youre finish looping through the rows the table will be locked and other users will get applications hanging waiting for table locks. Disabling the lock can be even worse, since its possible to read duplicate rows, parts of uncommitted transactions and all sorts of horrible things can happen.